# How to get values of multiple URL variables after the hash sign

Tags: javascript, url, url-parameters

Let's say i have this URL:

http://www.example.com/#articles/123456/

I want to get the values after the `#` in `JS`.

Which are: ***articles*** and ***123456***

I was able to get the whole string using:

```
var type = window.location.hash.substr(1);
```

The result was: ***articles/123456/***

Is there a way to get each variable alone ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
var type = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var parts = type.split("/");

console.log(parts[0]) // -> articles
console.log(parts[1]) // -> 123456
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the sort of thing your looking for.

```
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
    var url = 'http://www.example.com/#articles/123456/';
    var bitAfterHash = url.split('#').pop();
    var parts = bitAfterHash.split('/');
    var firstPart = parts[0];
    var lastPart = parts.pop() == '' ? parts[parts.length - 1] : parts.pop();
    $('p').html(firstPart + ' : ' + lastPart);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/58we82bh/)**

Hope this helps.

*Edit:* or in a plain js function that you pass the url to.

```
function getUrlParts(url){
    var bitAfterHash = url.split('#').pop();
    var parts = bitAfterHash.split('/');
    var firstPart = parts[0];
    var lastPart = parts.pop() == '' ? parts[parts.length - 1] : parts.pop();
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML= firstPart + ' : ' + lastPart;
};
```

Comment: Where you've found an indication for the presence of jQuery?

Comment: @Andreas I've edited my answer to include a plain js function for it. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    var url = "http://www.example.com/#articles/123456/";
    var lastIndex = lastIndex = url.endsWith("/") ? url.length-1: url.length;
    var hashIndexPlusOne = url.lastIndexOf('#') + 1; 
    var startIndex = url[hashIndexPlusOne]==="/" ?  hashIndexPlusOne + 1 : hashIndexPlusOne;
    values = url.substring(startIndex , lastIndex).split("/");

    //Result: 
    //values[0] = articles, values[1]= 123456
```